# Dynamic lambda expression with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have the following entity:

```
public enum RecordType
{
    Person,
    Company,
    //etc...
}

public class Entity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public RecordType RecordType {get; set;}
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public int CompanyId {get; set;}
    public Person Person {get; set;}
    public Company Company {get; set;}
}
```

Depending on the `RecordType`, the entity will either save in the `PersonId` or the `CompanyId` table columns.

For loading an entity from the db, I use eager loading in such a way:

```
public Entity Get(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> where)
{
    return Get(where, x => x.Person,
                      x => x.Company);
}

public Entity Get(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<Entity, object>>[] include)
{
    var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>, IQueryable<Entity>>
              (dbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

    return set.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

To limit the size and complexity of the SQL statement sent and the resultset returned by db, I was wondering if it's possible to have the `Get` method look like this:

```
public Entity Get(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> where)
{
    return Get(where, x => x.Person.When(x.RecordType == Person),
                      x => x.Company.When(x.RecordType == Company);
}
```

So that joins to associated tables are only added depending on the value of the `RecordType` column. Note: The above is not valid code, just to show how it might be implemented.

Is there a way to implement this feature?

Comment: What would the SQL that you expect as output against the database look like? I don't see how the database should process this command. Furthermore, I don't think it is even useful, though I am not so sure about that. A join works in O(log n) and log(n/2) = log n - log 2 so you would not save much time.

Comment: Make a class that derives from `ExpressionVisitor` class and pass it `where.Body` then inspect `node.Member.DeclaringType` in `VisitMember` override to determine the type.